# How to retrieve email and phone_number from AWS Mobile Hub in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

Does anyone know how to retrieve email and phone_number (just as the following picture shows) from AWS Mobile Hub in Swift?

[image: Picture]

I only know how to retrieve an username with the following code:

```
  let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider:nil)
  let configuration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: "clientId", clientSecret: "clientSecret", poolId: "poodId")
  AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: configuration, forKey: "Users")
  let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "Users")
  print(pool.currentUser()?.username)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct way:

```
@objc func retrieveFromAttributes() {

        let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
        let newProfileAttributes: ProfileAttributes = ProfileAttributes()
        newProfileAttributes._userId = AWSIdentityManager.default().identityId
        dynamoDbObjectMapper.load(ProfileAttributes.self, hashKey: newProfileAttributes._userId, rangeKey: "Vincent Sun", completionHandler: { (objectModel: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Amazon DynamoDB Read Error: \(error)")
                return
            }
                print("An item was read.")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.nameTextField.text = objectModel?.dictionaryValue["_nickname"] as? String
            }


        })


    }
```